# Could not complete vertical scroll of Listview inside InteractiveViewer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a requirement where I need to scroll through a list of images and also zoom and pan them. Very similar to a pdf document viewer. So I Used a ListView to show the pages and added the ListView as child to InteractiveViewer.

After zooming in I could not scroll to the top or bottom end of the ListView.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: InteractiveViewer(
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, _index) {
            print(_index);
            return Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.1,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Page index: $_index'),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        scaleEnabled: true,
        panEnabled: true,
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Screen recording of the issue faced]

I guess it might be due to the InteractiveViewer handling the scroll gesture of ListView.

Is there a way to avoid vertical gesture to be handled by InteractiveViewer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to make the two element have their scroll behavior working together, as `InteractiveViewer` allows you to move after zooming in your image.

Would it fulfill your requirement to set the image to fullscreen  when taping on the image to zoom ?

That way you keep the scroll handled by the `ScrollView` and separate the `InteractiveViewer` to another view.

Something like that, you wrap all of your images with the `ImageDetails` widget and remove your `InteractiveViewer` from the `Scaffold`:

```
class ImageDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;

  const ImageDetails({Key key, this.url}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'tag$url',
          child: NetworkImage(
            imageUrl: url,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            return FullScreenImage(
              url: url,
            );
          }));
        });
  }
}

class FullScreenImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;

  const FullScreenImage({Key key, this.url})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        maxScale: 2.0,
        minScale: 1.0,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          body: Center(
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'tag$url',
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child:
                    NetworkImage(imageUrl: url, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I too thought of this but I am preparing a PDF document viewer and scaling indiviual pages does not provide a neat UI for document viewing